# Dúvida - SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como faço no sql server para pegar os os registros maiores do que 10 dias a partir da data atual, ou seja, no mês atual, quero pegar todos os registros anteriores ao dia 01-08. Tentei dessa forma, mas não retornou nada.

```
SELECT
S.SolID [Chamado],
UC.UsuNome [Cliente],
C.Descricao [Curva ABC],

CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData,103) [Data de Abertura]
FROM Solicitacao S
LEFT JOIN Usuario UC on UC.Usuid = S.UsuIDCliente
LEFT JOIN CurvaABC C on C.CurvaID = UC.CurvaID

LEFT JOIN Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
WHERE S.SolStatus <> 9 and CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData,103) = getdate() - 10
and U.UsuIDGrupo = 1151
```

Comment: S.SolData é um campo do tipo datetime ou varchar() no banco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função DATEDIFF para realizar essa comparação. Para isso, estou considerado que o campo SolData é do tipo DATETIME.

Basicamente, basta colocar isso na sua cláusula WHERE.

```
DATEDIFF(dd,S.SolData,getdate()) >= 10
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
S.SolData <= getdate() - 10
```

Porém, a vantagem da DATEDIFF é que você pode especificar que o intervalo de data a ser comparado é em Dia, Mes, Ano, Hora, Minuto, Segundo, etc.

No caso acima, o DATEDIFF está retornado a diferença, em dias (parametro `dd`), entre a `SolData` e a data atual do Banco. Se essa diferença for `>=` a 10 dias, então os registros que atendem serão retornados.

Comment: Valeu grande. Obrigado

Comment: Bom dia @cantoni.. Como sempre digo.. vivendo e aprendendo :) Essa eu não conhecia.. Obrigado por compartilhar :) Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde @Renan Bessa

> Como faço no sql server para pegar os os registros maiores do que 10
>   dias a partir da data atual

Para PEGAR TODAS AS DATAS MAIORES QUE 10 DIAS seria :

```
SELECT * FROM clinica.teste
where
(data_nascimento > curdate()+10);
select * from teste;
```

Data ATUAL = CURDATE(); 
Data ATUAL + 10 DIAS  = CURDATE() + 10; 
Para pegar as menores é só inverter o sinal de > 
Espero ter entendido sua pergunta :) 
Abraços

Comment: Valeu grande. Obrigado